# Sorted by the last item in a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, matrix

By last item, I mean the last item in a list contained within a list, and those lists to be order based on the last number of the internal lists. I know, it's confusing... Here's an example

```python3
my_list = [[1,71,3],[141,2,5],[13,2,4],[1,20,1]]


def sort_function:
  pass
  #Sort code


print(sort_function(my_list))

>>> [[1,20,1],[1,71,3],[13,2,4],[141,2,5]]
```

I hope I explained what I wanted to happen with limited vagueness. I am working on a Z-buffer for a program of mine (a little 3D toy project) and this is all I can think of that will work. (I have a list of all of the verticies and I want to sort them first then load them into the screen). Since I want the ones in the back loaded first, I will just reverse the list with [:-1] or [-1:] or whatever it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort via the `key` parameter with a lambda function:

```
my_list = [[1,71,3],[141,2,5],[13,2,4],[1,20,1]]
new_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 20, 1], [1, 71, 3], [13, 2, 4], [141, 2, 5]]
```